# Get index of fibonacci number

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I started learning it in the university few months ago.
I have a homework to print the index of a fibonacci number (if it is) or print 0 (if it's not). But the fibonacci is a little bit different. 
`F(n) = aF(n-1) + bF(n-2)`. Where a and b are given from the input. So i am continuing to the input:
1 1 (those are a and b)
4 (is the length of the numbers inputted)
13 14 9 5 (exact numbers)
. In this case this is the regular fibonacci sequence. So it have to print:
7 (fib(7) = 13)
0 (14 is not a fib number)
0 (9 is not a fib number)
5 (fib(5) = 5)

The constraints are:
0 < a,b < 100
count of the numbers < 10000 
and each number should be in the range [0, 1000000]
I did the output. It really prints me the indices but without 0s. Only 7 and 5. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int a,b;

int fib(int n)
{

    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return a*fib(n-1) + b*fib(n-2);
}


int main()
{
    int length;
    vector<int> v;
    int number;
    while (cin >> a >> b >> length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            cin >> number;
            v.push_back(number);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)   // 30 is max because 31 is beyond 1.000.000
            {
                if (v[i] == fib(j))
                {
                    cout << j << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        v.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I print the 0s there?

Comment: You should do some research on the Fibonacci numbers. There is a closed formula for the `n`th Fibonacci number. In other words, you just plug in `n` and it immediately spits out the answer. You might be able to use this to help with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example would be to make "find this number in the Fibonacci sequence" a function:

```
int get_index(int v)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)   // 30 is max because 31 is beyond 1.000.000
    {
        if (v == fib(j))
        {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If there was no return in the loop, we return 0 at the end of the function.

After that, you just use it in your main code, like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << get_index(v[i]) << endl;
        }
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int a,b;

int fib(int n)
{

    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return a*fib(n-1) + b*fib(n-2);
}

int get_index(int v)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)   // 30 is max because 31 is beyond 1.000.000
    {
        if (v == fib(j))
        {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int length;
    vector<int> v;
    int number;
    while (cin >> a >> b >> length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            cin >> number;
            v.push_back(number);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << get_index(v[i]) << endl;
        }
        v.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)   // 30 is max because 31 is beyond 1.000.000
        {
            if (v[i] == fib(j))
            {
                flag = false;
                cout << j << endl;
            }
        }
       if(flag) cout << "0\n";   
 }
```

Comment: That was the fastest way. Thank you for the fast reaction it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

You need a way to indicate that a match was found and then after the loop finishes, if no match was found then print out 0.